# How do you get lmFuncs functions of the rfe function in caret to do a logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, caret

I've been experimenting with the `rfe` function in the `caret` package to do logistic regression with feature selection. I used the `lmFuncs` functions with the following `rfeContol` :

`ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs,
                     method = 'cv',
                     rerank=TRUE,
                     saveDetails=TRUE,
                     verbose = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "all",
                     number=100)`

Below is the structure of the `rfe` call:

`fit.rfe=rfe(df.preds,df.depend, metric='RMSE',sizes=c(5,10,15,20), rfeControl=ctrl)`

`df.preds` is a data frame of inputs to the model. `df.depend` is a vector of 1 or 0 corresponding to each row in `df.preds` to indicate response.

The resulting model accessed in from the `fit` object in the `rfe` object is of class `lm` and produces predicted values of less than zero and greater than 1 when I use the following code with the `predict` function:

`predict(fit.rfe$fit,df,type='response')`

Given I'm expecting this to be a logistic, all predicted values should greater than zero and less than one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using 100-fold cross-validation is not advisable.  Practically speaking, each fold is going to be 99% similar to another fold.  Use a smaller number of folds (like 5 or 10) to get more new data in each fold (mix it up more) and then if you want to do repeats, specify `repeats=`.  Otherwise you won't really simulate how the technique performs on new data.  See this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/variance-and-bias-in-cross-validation-why-does-leave-one-out-cv-have-higher-var) for comparison of k-fold and leave-one-out CV, which is what you approach as `number=` goes up

Comment: Has you try lrFunc instead of lmFunc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lmFuncs` is fitting linear regression. Just type `lmFuncs$fit` to see. Try to rewrite it:

```
lmFuncs$fit<-function (x, y, first, last, ...){   
     tmp <- as.data.frame(x)   
     tmp$y <- y   
 glm(y ~ ., data = tmp,family=binomial)   
}
```

Note, that I don't know how to attach `<environment: namespace:caret>` and what is its meaning. You may try this trick on your data and comment the result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get an error when I try to rewrite. `lmFuncs$fit<-function (x, y, first, last, ...){ tmp <- as.data.frame(x) tmp$y <- y glm(y ~ ., data = tmp,family=binomial) } Error: unexpected symbol in "lmFuncs$fit<-function (x, y, first, last, ...){ tmp <- as.data.frame(x) tmp"`

Comment: Original code with paragraphes was going fine. I have just edited my answer.

Comment: I got it to work by defining a new object called glmFuncs using the following code: `glmFuncs=lmFuncs

glmFuncs$fit=function (x, y, first, last, ...) 
{
  tmp <- as.data.frame(x)
  tmp$y <- y
  glm(y ~ ., data = tmp, family=binomial(link='logit'))}`. It is doing exactly what I want it to do. Thank you soooo much.

Comment: It's telling me {: task 6 failed - "Results do not have equal lengths"