# Testing set accuracy by using cross validation using xgboost with caret

Tags: cross-validation, caret, boosting

I am working on an xgboost model using caret. I'm using cross validation, but don't know if I'm understanding it correctly. As I understand, it creates multiple training and test sets. Does this mean that the data doesn't have to be splitted to training and test sets before the modeling?

If so, how do I obtain the mean absolute errors from the test set? I am using R.

I tried to get them using the following code:

```
postResample(pred = pred, obs = obs)[3]
```

but the MAEs seem rather optimistic. Is it possible to obtain the MAEs just for the test set?

I am also using hyperparameter tuning, if that matters. The model is also linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; the data used from the `train` function essentially act as train and validation sets; they do not reflect "true performance" on unseen data.

Yes, we will have to use a separate test set to assess the performance of the particular algorithm on unseen data. To that extent, the use of nested cross-validation might be beneficial for this, this post on *[Nested cross validation for model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection)* gives an extensive discussion on the topic.

In any case, we can obtain MAE on the test-set by simply using `predict` on the test explanatory variables and then comparing the predicted response to the actual response from the test set. As you correctly noticed, if we do not use a separate test-set the performance metrics will (very likely) be optimistic.

Comment: And this is all the case _because_ OP is doing hyperparameter tuning, correct? If OP had a single model being trained on the training folds and scored on the testing folds, then the average score would be an unbiased estimator?

Comment: Yes, correct is because of the tuning. Yes it will be (practically) unbiased but do read this mega-thread on: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/ to get the full idea! Variance can really hurt us! ("Practically" because we will not use all of our data in the training set, so we do have minor bias there.)