# Cross validation and type I, type II error

Tags: cross-validation, type-i-and-ii-errors

In the context of building a predictive model, I understand that cross validation (such as K-Fold) is a technique to find the optimal hyper-parameters in reducing bias and variance [somewhat](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61783/bias-and-variance-in-leave-one-out-vs-k-fold-cross-validation).

Recently, I was told that cross validation also reduces type I and type II error. To my knowledge, type I error (false positive) and type II error (false negative) are normally discussed in the context of assessing hypothesis (e.g. H<sub>o</sub> = μ vs H<sub>A</sub> ≠ μ), classification of samples (e.g. medical tests of having a disease vs not having a disease).

I'm very confused. My intuition tells me that cross validation has nothing to do with type I or type II error. For example, in classification, one can adjust the threshold to change the proportion of false positive and false negative. But I can't come up with any concrete proof.

So my question is: does cross validation reduce type I and type II error, ideally with proof (in classification and regression models).

Comment: Every time you use a regression model, no matter what it is, you are basically adjusting coefficients or functions to your predictive variables. I am not certain about this but what comes to my mind as reducing type I and II errors might by under the hypothesis that those coefficients (or your predictive model in general) has significance. Hypothesis testing can be used to determine the significance of the whole Multilinear Regression Model. Read, for example, about the F statistic you get when you use a Linear Regression Model.